# qobject_cast no Q_OBJECT macro error

Tags: c++, qt, casting

I have a slot that is triggered by a QFutureWatcher. I'm trying to cast the sender to get the results

```
QFutureWatcher<QPair<QImage,QString>>* QFW = qobject_cast<QFutureWatcher<QPair<QImage,QString>>*>(sender());
```

but keep getting

```
error: static assertion failed: qobject_cast requires the type to have a Q_OBJECT macro
```

I'm not really sure what's wrong here, these are all Qt built-in types, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are missing `#include <QFutureWatcher>` so the compiler does not know that QFutureWatcher inherits from QObject.

Comment: I thought about it too, but including the header didn't help.

Comment: Does dynamic_cast<> work instead?

Comment: It does, thanks! But i'm still wondering why the qobject_cast fails...

Answer (score 2):

You have to put Q_OBJECT in the Class Definition, like this:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
 // ^^^^^^^^^^
public:
    MyClass();
/*...*/
}
```

Comment: The class I'm using it in already had this macro. I think it's complaining about the QFutureWatcher<QPair<QImage,QString>>